# Delete the first column of a selected table on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the snippet below. How can I trim (delete the first column) of the selected table on the fly and append it to the `#output`?

```js
$("#select-tbl").on("click", function(){
    $('#output').append( $("#tbl-box").html());
});
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

th:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
td:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tbl-box">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br />
<button id="select-tbl"> Select Table</button>
<br />
<br />
<div id="output"> </div>
```

Comment: so what do you mean append it to output? Since output is a div and the original is a table, did you just want the data (the things as a string maybe separated by a comma), or did you also want it formatted like a table with rows?

Answer (score 0):

I would add this to the event handler:

```
$('#output > table td:first-child').remove();
$('#output > table th:first-child').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [demo](https://jsbin.com/fefapuqowo/edit?html,js,console,output) on JS Bin. Please check it out.

Basically, I think the idea is to retrieve the first column (with the header), and append it to the `output` div, and then delete it in the original table. Below is the JavaScript code:

```
$("#select-tbl").on("click", function(){
    // get the header of the first column
    var header = $('th:nth-child(1)').html();
    var table = $('<table></table>');
    table.append('<tr><th>' + header + '</th></tr>');
    // get each <td> element
    for (var i = 0; i < $("td:nth-child(1)").length; i++){
      var row = $('<tr></tr>');
      row.append('<td>' + $("td:nth-child(1)").eq(i).text() + '</td>');
      row.appendTo(table);
    }
    $('#output').append(table);
    // remove in the original table
    $('#tbl-box > table td:first-child').remove();
    $('#tbl-box > table th:first-child').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Shiving but actually I was looking for exactly the opposite of what you are getting now! :-) I would like to get rid of the first coulmn , indeed but I think I am getting an idea from what you have done!